# logistic regression test error rate in intercept-only model

Tags: regression, logistic, cross-validation

I'm using logistic regression with LOOCV and am balancing the classes for the two responses.  I noticed that with my model, the test error rate is decent (0.22) and the predictor variable is significant at alpha level of 0.001.  However, when I was looking at the test error rate for an intercept-only model, it was 0.26.  I would have expected it to be larger, given the classes are balanced and there are 45 samples in each class.  Is the low test error rate a result of over-fitting the model?  I thought that LOOCV was the best way to prevent over-fitting, since you are both training and testing on all of the available data.  I would appreciate any insight into why the test error rate of the intercept model would be nearly as good as the model with a significant predictor.  Should also mention the AIC was definitely lower with the model including the predictor variable.

Comment: Do you have enough data for a simple 50/50 test/training data split? Have you tried that? What are the results of that?

Comment: I haven't tried a 50/50 split, but I have 45 observations in each class, so I would end up with 22 observations in the training and 22 in the testing set.  I was under the impression that LOOCV was superior method to a two-fold CV.  Is there a good reason to try two-fold?

Comment: I'm not so sure that LOOCV is uniformly superior to an n-fold approach. Why do you think this to be true?

Comment: Well, I don't know if I would say uniformly, but in general I thought it was a superior approach, because there is less bias than two-fold CV since you use the whole data set to train and test the model.  Am I missing an important distinction between the two approaches?  I'm not opposed to trying two-fold CV, but I would suspect that estimate is more biased.  To get back to the main question I have is why would an intercept-only model perform almost as well as a model that contains significant predictors.

Comment: Upvoting this question because I wish it was answered or at least led to a discussion of possible issues and complications in model evaluation. I don't think situations like the one OP discusses here are too rare - insights regarding these types of (relatively) common occurrences would be useful.